# Windows 10 failed to install English (GB) typing, English (GB) optical character recognition ...... error code: 0x800F0908

Tags: windows-10, installation, english

This problem happened on yesterday.

I did not do anything and Windows 10 start to install

1. English (GB) typing
2. English (GB) optical character recognition
3. Chinese (PRC) optical character recognition
4. Chinese (PRC) typing
5. Chinese (Simplified) Supplemental Fonts

And kept trying to install again and again, very annoying.

Error code for all packages is **0x800F0908**.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected to my home wifi and the wifi I set it as a metered connection.

So, you can try to turn off the `Set as metered connection`.

[image]

I hope this will help.

Comment: How is this the answer? What problem does it actually solve? Does it allow install of the requested packages or just stop them trying to be installed?

Comment: @johnstaveley It allows windows to install packages. I think windows will not use a metered network to download update.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click Windows icon in the lower left corner of Windows 10 desktop or press the Windows key on your keyboard to open the Start menu.
2. Click All apps in the bottom of the Start menu, expand Windows System folder, right-click on *Command Prompt* and select *Run as administrator*.
3. Try this command as administrator:

   ```
   schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\LanguageComponentsInstaller\Installation" /Disable
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

1) Manually install from the [cab files](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-version-1709-language-packs-direct-download-links/#Windows_10_Version_1709_language_packs_Download_Links) via lpksetup

2) Disable the scheduled task

Microsoft > Windows > LanguageComponentsInstaller > Installation

Hopefully Microsoft will release the updates soon, then these workarounds are not required

First option helped me.
[Original Thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/optional-language-features-fail-to-install/cd2494a9-2311-4e28-99a0-7de390826e45)